# Spring Bean Injection of Interface object

Tags: spring

The code is as follows

```
public interface ExperimentConfig {
  Boolean func1();
}

public class RuntimeConfig implements IntializingBean{
  private ExperimentConfig experimentConfig;

  public ExperimentConfig getExperimentConfig() {
    return experimentConfig;
  }

  public void setExperimentConfig(ExperimentConfig experimentConfig) {
    this.experimentConfig = experimentConfig;
  }
}

public class Util
{
  public static ExperimentConfig experimentConfig()
  { 
     return new Builder.build(1,"a",89);
  }
```

Spring XML file

```
<bean id="RuntimeConfig"
   class="bizconfig.RuntimeConfig"scope="singleton">

   <property name="experimentConfig">
      <bean class="bizconfig.Util" factory-method="experimentConfig"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This code dosent seem to work. I think I'm using Spring the wrong way when an Interface is a property. How do I fix this.

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="util" class="Util">
...properties 
</bean>

<bean id="RuntimeConfig"
   class="bizconfig.RuntimeConfig"scope="singleton">

   <property name="experimentConfig">
      <bean factory-bean="util" factory-method="experimentConfig"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I dont understnad by what you mean by "...properties". Util only has static functions

Comment: if you dont have any other properties you dont need to